# Opencart migration Shared hosting to VPS

Tags: hosting, opencart

I migrated my opencart website from shared hosting to VPS but it gives me an error. "Error: Could not load cache driver file cache!".
 Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `\system\library\cache` directory in your OpenCart installation.

You can confirm this by looking here on your OpenCart setup:

```
[yourstore root]\system\library\cache\
```

I just ran into this problem myself, and found out my FTP client (Transmit on OS X) was "kindly" skipping over directories named `cache` when I was doing my upload of OpenCart. The `cache` directory in the system library contains the PHP files (`apc.php`, `file.php` and `mem.php`) which set up the various cache classes used by OpenCart.

Needless to say, when this is missing, you get that error.